# Database Generator php and mysql

Tags: database, web, phpmyadmin

How do I create a database generator to allows a user to create his own table in the database without access to PHPMyAdmin and without any emphasized text knowlege about PHP or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You at-least need the sql file to run so that the database can be created....
create the sql file (the whole backup of the database along with subroutines)

just load the database via this command

```
  mysql -u'root' -p'password' databaseName < /path/to/file.sql
```

In order to run mysql, it should be in your environment variable..

Comment: how will you define the types? and rest of the key constraints? 
Why don't you use any sql client like HEIDI SQL or SQL YOG? It provides the complete UI and you dont need to use any sql there..

Comment: Yes, you will have to pass the Hostname (ip), username and password...but make sure the database user has the write to access the database from % (all places)